# ¿El body de mi request en nodejs esta vacio?

Tags: nodejs, express, requests

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
//constante del puerto
const PORT = process.env.PORT||3000;

require('./database');

//el metodo json es para obtener el body del request en formato json
app.use(express.json());

//importamos la ruta
app.use('/api',require('./routes/index'));

app.listen(PORT);
console.log('Server on port', PORT);
```

Este es el codigo fuente de mi app.js, que se encarga de levantar mi servidor node, en este archivo importo la ruta de mi archivo index.js:

```
const { Router } = require('express');
const router = Router();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var urlencodeParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false});

//importamos el usuario
const User = require('../models/user');

router.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.send('Hello World');
    console.log(req)
});

//ruta para registrar un usuario
router.post('/signup', urlencodeParser, (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.send('Testing Signup');
});

module.exports = router;
```

en la ruta que uso para registrar el usuario, imprimo en un console log el body del request, pero en el console log, solo se imprime esto {}, y imprimir el request completo, me di cuenta que el atributo body estaba vacio

Comment: Deberías incluir el middleware bodyParser en la ruta también:
router.get('/', urlencodeParser, (req, res) => { 
    console.log(req.body);
    res.send('Hello World');
})

Comment: si el body que envias del cliente tiene el `content-type: application/json` tienes que añadir el middleware `bodyParser,json()`

Comment: ¿el bodyparser.json() debo añadirlo en mi archivo app.js o en mi archivo index.js?

Comment: El bodyparser.json() ya lo tienes con: app.use(express.json()), aunque deberías instalar la dependencia body-parser y sustituirlo por app.use(bodyparser.json()). También podrías hacerlo para el urlencoded. Justo debajo de donde tienes: app.use(express.json()) puedes poner-> app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false})) de esta forma no tendrás que ponerlo en cada una de las rutas.